# Managing several versions of angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

For some reasons, I have to use angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.22 at my work on one project.
But on new projects I would like to use the latest version without being bothered by this constraint.

I installed angular cli in global and in the devDependencies

How can I use the "local" version of angular-cli in the project ?
I tried `./node_modules/.bin/ng generate [...]` but it doesn't work

Thank you !

Comment: Why not? What's the issue you are facing?